# SQL Help Requested: SELECT Table A Joined with Table B (Max or Null)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, left-join, inner-join

In table A (alias ai), I have a list of items.  In table B (alias aib), I have the price history for all of the items of table A, but not all items, for those, I need to SELECT NULL.  I need to select the item from table A, it's maximum price from table B or NULL.

Here's what I have, but it's not quite working, I'm getting duplicate records if table B has an extensive price history.

Here's the not exactly working query:

```
SELECT *

FROM ItemGroup aig 

INNER JOIN Item ai ON ai.groupID = aig.ID 

LEFT JOIN Item_Prices aib ON ai.ID = aib.ItemID 

WHERE aig.ID = @groupID AND 
(aib.max_price = (SELECT MAX(price) AS highprice FROM Item_Prices 
  WHERE ItemID = ai.ID) 
  OR aib.price IS NULL) 

ORDER BY end_date
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Respectfully,

Ray

Comment: is there a table C in here as well?

Comment: Sorry for the leaving out important facts: SQL Server 2008 R2 and Yes, there is a table C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@squillman has almost nailed it. Optimized:

```
SELECT GroupID      = aig.groupID     ,
       ItemID       = ai.ID as ItemID ,
       HighestPrice = aib.HighestPrice
FROM      Item        ai
left join ( select ItemID ,
                   HighestPrice = max(price)
            from Item_Prices
            group by ItemID
          ) aib on aib.ItemID = ai.ID
WHERE ai.groupID = @groupID
ORDER BY end_date
```

If all you're looking at from the table ItemGroup is the group id...you don't need the table: you've already got groupID in the Item table, so ItemGroup is unnecessary, though you'll need to keep it if you require other attributes from ItemGroup. Leaving ItemGroup in shouldn't affect the query plan much: you want at most one group, and presumably ItemGroup has a covering index on groupID.

`distinct` is unnecessary with the subquery: `group by ItemID` makes the subquery result set unique by ItemID. This has implications for performance: `distinct` means the engine has to ensure the result set is unique. Hopefully, the optimizer would realize that the `group by` makes the set unique and discard the `distinct`, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: Works perfectly with a little tweaking for SQL Server 2008 R2.  Thank you all for your overwhelming support!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemGroup aig
INNER JOIN Item ai ON ai.groupID = aig.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ItemID,MAX(max_price)
    FROM Item_Prices
    GROUP BY ItemID
) aib ON ai.ID=aib.ItemID
WHERE aig.ID = @groupID
ORDER BY end_date
```

The subquery gets your max price by ItemID and should thus filter out the duplicates.

Comment: Don't need `distinct` in the subquery. `Group by ItemID` makes the subquery results distinct by itemID.

Comment: @Niholas True dat...  Took it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ray, are you just using the item table to join the two tables together? If you don't need anything else from item table for the rest of the query then it is not really necessary.

If **all** you really want to do is "select the item from table A, it's maximum price from table B or NULL." it could be as simple as this if Item_Prices.price allows null's.

```
SELECT a.ItemName, MAX(b.price) AS 'MaxPrice' 
FROM Item AS a INNER JOIN Item_Prices AS b
ON a.groupID = b.ItemID
GROUP BY a.ItemName
```

Here is whats in my Item_Prices table

[image: Contents of Item_Prices listing several null and duplicate values]

Here is what is in my Item table

[image: Contents of Item]

Outcome of the query:

[image: Output from query]

Here is the design view of my Item table, the groupID is the primary key.

[image: Design view of Item table with groupID as primary key]

Here is the design view of my Item_Prices table, you can set ItemID as the foreign key

[image: Design view of Item_Prices with itemID as primary key]

If you want to select data from separate tables you don't need that third table to link them up for you or anything.  As long as they have some type of unique identifier in Table A(primary key) and a matching key (usually foreign key) in Table B that links up, you are golden!

**If you did intend to get that third table in there for another field, then disregard!**  I just wanted to whip up a quick example to show you that because when I was in work/school I saw a lot of people using a third table to link tables together which makes no sense, most of the time!

Comment: thanks for going the extra mile.  Sorry, yes there was a table C.

Comment: Not a problem, I wanted to get that out there for anyone with the nasty habit described :P

Comment: You `JOIN` by `groupID` which is a key but you `GROUP BY ItemName` which isn't a key and is nullable: is this really what you intended i.e. group items with different "primary identifiers" but with the same (possibly NULL) name? It seems to me that you'd get more reliable results to `GROUP BY groupID` i.e. the key.

Comment: No... you have to group by ItemName according to SQL syntax. (MAX function)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ...
From ItemGroup As AIG
    Join Item As AI
        On AI.ID = AIG.ID
Where AIG.Id = @groupId
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From Item_Prices As IP1
                    Join    (
                            Select IP2.ItemID, Max( IP2.Price ) As Price
                            From Item_Prices As IP2
                            Group By IP2.ItemId
                            ) As MaxPrices
                        On MaxPrices.ItemID = IP1.ItemID
                            And MaxPrices.Price = IP2.Price
                Where IP1.ItemID = AI.ID
                Union All
                Select 1
                From Item_Prices As IP1
                Where IP1.ItemID = AI.ID
                    And IP1.Price Is Null
                )
Order By End_Date
```